# Why prevent high frequency input into the loud speaker using a low pass filter?

Tags: speakers, high-frequency, oscillation

[image]

**As much information as possible about this figure would be helpful**

From what my professor said, "Q2 oscillates when we connect a Loud Speaker, this might generate high frequency signals, so we use a low pass filter to filter them out". I understand that we need low pass filter to filter out high frequencies but (why is high frequency bad for Loud speaker?). Some help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the professor should have said is: "oscillations may occur, R6 and C3 help prevent this".

If there are oscillations, it's not **only** because of Q2. I see a feedback (?) line connecting to R5, feedback can cause oscillations if not done properly.

The network of R6 and C3 provide a defined impedance at high frequencies and that helps with the stability of the feedback loop. The loudspeaker might have a high impedance at the frequency where oscillations can occur. This high impedance increases the loopgain of the feedback loop and that **helps** oscillations. By adding R6 and C3 there is a low(er) impedance at the these frequencies which **lowers** the loopgain and that **prevents** oscillations.

So that R6 and C3 are **not** there to prevent high frequencies from getting to the loudspeaker ! They are there to prevent oscillations and to keep the amplifier well behaved.

Comment: I will re-upload the entire schematics, is it ok if you have a look and describe me few things? i have a defense coming up for my project. @FakeMoustache

Comment: Hmm, a class B amplifier. Indeed there is feedback like I expected. I build a similar thing 30 years ago when I was a teenager ;-)

Comment: hehehehee!! that sounds cool.... :) if you have some time, could you explain me about this schematics, i have to defend this next week, but i don't know what kind of question i can expect from my professors. Thank you @FakeMoustache

Comment: For me to explain something you will need to ask a specific question. It's late here so I might answer tomorrow. Just so you know. But I can answer a question, no problem.

Comment: Humm, ok. 1. why do we prefer PWM instead of sinusoidal input? 2. why do need to bock DC(C1) at the inverting input? 3. Why do we use (R3)? i might have to ask you more questions :) ... is it possible to help me with them too?

Comment: @FakeMoustache. This is just an observation: By itself this is a poor amplifier design as the output transistors have no bias diodes. At low volume the THD will be very high, creating a noticeable distortion with sine waves.

Comment: 1) Who prefers PWM input and why ? It depends on how you want to use this amplifier. As a linear amplifier we would input a sine wave. For class D operation (switching) indeed you could use a PWM signal as input **but** this PWM frequency cannot be so high because this amplifier is not very fast due to the opamp. This is a "slow" general purpose opamp. For a proper class D amplifier I would use a different design.

Comment: 2) we need C1 because this amplifier needs to bias its input itself through R5. If you leave out C1 then the DC level of the input becomes very critical. Choose it wrongly and the output of the amplifier will be stuck at Ground (0V) or Vcc (5V). With C1 in place only the AC component of the input signal will reach the opamp's input which is what you want so the opamp's feedback loop will set the DC level at the input to the proper value (2.5 V, which is set by R1 and R2).

Comment: 3) R3, I do not see an R3 ! Your observation about the distortion is correct, this amplifier is a class B amplifier (the output transistors can be switched off completely) and therefore it will have a some crossover distortion. The high gain of the opamp does compensate for that in some respect but the distortion will never be absent.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Sorry for the delay, and thank you for your replies, I wanted to ask (why do we also use two transistors? why do we need them?)

Comment: You mean the two transistors at the output ? It is possible using only one but then the other would need to be replaced by a resistor. For low power amplifiers (not driving a speaker) this is a common configuration. Google: "common collector circuit" and you see what I mean. The two transistors form a "push-pull" configuration, one pushes current into the speaker (here NPN Q1) and the other (PNP, Q2) pulls current from the speaker. This makes it possible that the current can be positive and negative. Which is what you need for audio signals.

Comment: @FakeMoustache  i'm a bit confused. It will still work the same even if we replace (any one) of those two transistors with resistor? or did you mean we it will work but we will have problems if we replay one transistor with a resistor ? :) sorry for being dumb

Comment: @FakeMoustache also, for question1.. what happens when we use high frequency PWM when the opamp is slow? thank you

Comment: Yes the circuit will still work if we replaced Q1 **or** Q2 with a resistor of for example 100 ohms. **But** then the current through that resistor (and also the current to the speaker flowing through that resistor) would be limited as it is always 100 ohms.

Comment: If you would use PWM with a slow opamp, the opamp will behave as a filter, it will work on the average value of the PWM signal. But it is better practice to filter **before** the signal goes into the opamp. Depending on the opamp it might act strange with signals that are too fast for it.

Comment: @FakeMoustache as you said "The loudspeaker might have a high impedance at the frequency where oscillations can occur.", i couldn't figure out why at high impedance this will happen? :)

Comment: As I said, that has to do with the loopgain of the feedback loop in this amplifier. Although since the output stage are two Common Collector stages(Q1, Q2) and these will have a low output impedance (property of a CC stage), so the load impedance (R6, C3 and the loudspeaker) should not influence the loop gain so much in this case. R6 and C3 also help to provide a low load impedance at high frequencies (because the loudspeaker will be inductive and therefore has a high impedance at high frequencies) which helps with transient behavior, meaning fast changing input signals.